# web api "get" method results in a view

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 2.0 web api with the following get method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> Get()
    {
        return await customerDataProvider.GetCustomers();
    }
```

In the startup class i have the following in configuration:

```
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
     });
```

when i run the application i get the results displayed as raw json in the browser.

I would like to add a view and to handle the results in that view meaning display them in a table and add some filtering and sorting options.

How can i achieve this? I saw different articles on how to add a view or a razor page to a project but none of them was similar to my case..

Thanks!

Comment: Refer [ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core - Sort, Filter, Paging - 3 of 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0#add-column-sort-links-to-the-students-index-page), where did it not work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I missed that article in my search, I'll look into it and hopefully will find the answer.